# the sum of degree of all vertices in tree with 10 vertices

Tags: graphs

let T be tree with 10 vertices.
what is the sum of degree of all vertices in tree[image]

Comment: How many edges will such a tree have? What is the relation between the sum of degrees and number of edges?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Fact one: graph is a tree on $n$ vertices, it has exactly $n-1$ edges https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)

Fact two: sum of all degrees is twice number of edges
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma

Thus, for $n=10$ we get

$\sum\limits_{v \in V} deg(v) = 2(n-1) = 18$

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).